# 100 % CPU usage threading LINUX despite time delays in while(1)

Tags: python, multithreading

Hi guys  I am using about 7 python threads in my program on a raspberry pi, and all of them are running in while(1), infinitely. SO the CPU usage is 100%. Any suggestions on how to reduce CPU usage ? I am already using delays of 0.1 (time.sleep(0.1)) at the beginning of every while loop.  Should I increase the timer  or is there any other better way of doing this ?

Comment: Are the loops doing useful work? If the program is doing something useful 100% cpu usage should be what you want.

Comment: It depends.  This could be as simple as setting longer delays.  What is the loop doing? You haven't told us much.  If the loop is checking for updates in a file or new files in a directory to process, it might be implemented more efficiently with [pyinotify](http://pyinotify.sourceforge.net/)